# Process jms message synchronously for a specific property group but concurrently among other groups

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I need help on JMS queue and message processing.

I have a scenario where messages needs to be processed synchronously for a specific property group, but can be done concurrently among different property groups.

I got some knowledge on message group and queues specific to each property. My thinking is, I want to do synchronous processing specific to a property group and there could be 7000 or more property group as such.

Definitely i cannot have 7000 queues. Please provide any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Concept of queue and message groups in ActiveMQ will serve the purpose.

Each incoming jms message should be set with header "JMSXGroupID". The value for 
the header should be specific to the group.

Now, concurrent consumers can listen to the queue. ActiveMQ will make sure, message with same group header value, will be sent to same consumer.

Refer to: http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html

Thanks.